# make python script use 2.7.8 instead of 2.6

Tags: python, alias

I have 2 versions of python installed on my server.

Python 2.6 in /usr/bin/python

Python 2.7.8 in /usr/src

[Python 2.7.8 install guide](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/)

How do I make python scripts use 2.7.8? instead of 2.6? 
how do I set up an alias?

Thanks

Comment: consider using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: OS is linux i suppose. Do you want all python scripts to run under 2.7?

Comment: Yes, Centos 6.6. Yes, please - all python scripts to run under 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
#!<path to your python interpreter>
```

as the first line of the script your run. Then just execute it.

Other option:

```
<path to your python interpreter> your_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. First, I would suggest you check your `$PATH` environment variable to see if it holds the path to both of your python versions. If it doesn't, you can either add the path or simply make a symlink to it from `/usr/bin/` and call it `python2.7`, for example.

Then you can use @Pavel's suggestion of specifying the path to the interpreter in the `shebang` of the file.

If you followed my previous instructions, your `shebang` should look something similar to the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

You could also use the second way @Pavel showed you, by simply calling the interpreter first in the terminal and pointing it to the script.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 my_script.py
```

The best option you have, which I recommend, is using `virtualenv` as suggested before, but only if you want it for specific scripts. If you want it globally, I would suggest you read further.

**Finally**, if you want all your scripts to run under `python 2.7` then I suggest you remove `python 2.6` and install the `2.7` version from the package manager, the right way, and save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thank you. So I installed python 2.7 using this [link] http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/ so the python 2.7 dir is in /usr/src/? How exactly do you add it to the $PATH environment variable? Thanks

Comment: @JohnBrady it is unadvisable, on a binary distribution, to compile something like that, if you don't know what you're doing. My recommendation is to undo what you did and add the repository of CentOS that has `python2.7` (http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) and install it from there